# Search Console alerts me to increased 404s but shows no data

Tags: google-search-console, 404

I recently changed the URL structure of a site I'm working on.  Today, I got an email notice from Google Search Console on 'Increase in “404” pages on mydomain.com'.  Actually, not surprising considering the changes.

But when I went to search console, looked at the message and clicked 'Check crawl errors', it shows 'no data' in the bottom pane.  The Desktop -> Not Found pane notes 170.

The actual view:
[image]

I went through the same thing about a week ago, and marked a done of URLs resolved.

I also did a fresh 'fetch, render and index'.  Didn't change anything.

**How can I see what the problem URLs are?**

Comment: I think you have hidden all the URLs by marking them "done".   They will re-appear in the report eventually if they are still 404.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I was thinking it might something like that.  Will let you know if they reappear.

Comment: If a page does not exist and you are getting valid 404 notices, marking them as fixed tells Google that they should exist and to try again. Leave valid 404s along and ignore them. This is a perfectly normal function of the web and expected. This is not a problem to fix.

Comment: As a side note, sometimes specific URLs do not show up for a few days even if the errors are noted.

Comment: FYI: A day or so later, the bottom data pane was filled out with some URLs

Answer (score 1):

Try using another tool such as Screaming Frog, Xenu or Integrity to crawl the website.

- If there are indeed errors on the website, those tools will show them as well and you can fix them.
- If, on the other hand, the other tools come up empty-handed in terms of errors, it's probably Google tripping up a bit, and either the error count will be lowered soon, or details will become available.